# how to pass in an object using UINavigation Controller and load to another page?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, xcode4.3, uistoryboard

I'm using storyboard to create my app. the first it run, it will show up all the data. After that if i click +, i will add a new data. if i click on the row, i will move to page that will show the data.

i'm using this but still got an error. here is my code.

```
    -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddUser"])
    {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        UserDetailViewController *userDetailViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        userDetailViewController.delegate = self;
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"UpdateUser"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        UserNHG *usernhg = [ListUserNHG objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        UINavigationController *navigationController = [segue.destinationViewController setUsernhg:usernhg]; // i got my error here  
        UserDetailViewController *userDetailViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        userDetailViewController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

here is my error message

```
Initializing 'UINavigationController *__strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'void';
```

if i only use this, i won't get the error.

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [segue destinationViewController];
```

but if i'm using that code, how can i pass my object? 
any idea how to solve this?

Comment: UINavigationController is window's rootViewController

Comment: @Prince - thanks for your answer. But can you explain more? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
 AppDelegate *objAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)objAppDelegate.window.rootViewController;
 UserDetailViewController *userDetailViewController = (UserDetailViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]; //must know correctly index of UserDetailViewController
```

**EDIT** : How to `pass object`:

```
Create UserNHG *selectedUser property in UserDetailViewController.
```

Now

```
userDetailViewController.selectedUser =  usernhg; //object passed
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.. but how do i pass my usernhg object?

Answer (score 0):

i just found it by reference to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672856/pass-int-variable-to-uitableview-through-uinavigationcontroller)

here is my code :

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    UserNHG *usernhg = [ListUserNHG objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [segue destinationViewController];
    TestViewController *testViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    testViewController.usernhg = usernhg;
testViewController.delegate = self;
```

thanks for your time. :)